# VS 2013 exception when using C++11 unrestricted unions

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, unions

Consider this code:

```
struct TNumeric {
    bool    Negative;
    wstring Integral;
    wstring Fraction;
};
union TValue {
    // The unnamed structs are needed because otherwise the compiler does not accept it...
    bool                Bit;
    struct{ TNumeric    Numeric; };
    struct{ wstring     Text; };
};

TNumeric Numeric;
TNumeric &rNumeric{ Numeric };
rNumeric.Integral = L"";
rNumeric.Integral.push_back( L'X' ); //OK, no problem

TValue Value;
TValue &rValue{ Value };
rValue.Text = L"";
rValue.Text.push_back( L'X' ); //OK, no problem

rValue.Numeric.Integral = L"";
rValue.Numeric.Integral.push_back( L'X' ); // Exception
```

In release mode there is no problem. When run in debug mode there is an exception at the last statement in method _Adopt of class _Iterator_base12 in xutility: `Access violation reading location 0x0000005C`.

In _Adopt the code is only run when `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2`. I tried with

```
#define _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 1
```

added in my main program but it remains defined as 2.
Is there a way to disable the check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VS 2013 [doesn't support C++11 unrestricted unions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#corelanguagetable), that is it implements unions as per C++03:

> An object
>   of a class with a non-trivial constructor (12.1), a non-trivial copy constructor (12.8), a non-trivial destructor
>   (12.4), or a non-trivial copy assignment operator (13.5.3, 12.8) cannot be a member of a union

You successfully fooled the compiler by using unnamed structs, but that doesn't solve the problem: the objects are non-trivial, and VS2013 doesn't support that.

When you switch to more C++11-compliant compiler, such as VS 2015, you'll have to implement constructor, destructor, copy constructor etc. for the union in a way that it safely constructs/destructs/copies appropriate part of the union. There's an example in the standard (I'm quoting C++14 draft N4140 [class.union]/4):

> Consider an object `u` of a union type `U` having non-static data
>   members `m` of type `M` and `n` of type `N`. If `M` has a non-trivial destructor and `N` has a non-trivial constructor
>   (for instance, if they declare or inherit virtual functions), the active member of `u` can be safely switched
>   from `m` to `n` using the destructor and placement new operator as follows:
>
> ```
> u.m.~M();
> new (&u.n) N;
> ```

Comment: Alternatively, `boost::variant` will take care of placement new and placement delete to construct/destroy elements in the union.

Comment: OK, very clear! As space is not a vital issue I'll just make the union a struct.